# What is the ibdata1 file in my /var/lib/mysql directory?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, troubleshooting, maintenance

Logging in to my Webmin control panel, I noticed that virtually all of my disk space is full. I searched for the ten largest files/ directories on my system and found that a file called ibdata1 is taking up around 94GB of space. It resides in my /var/lib/mysql directory.

What does ibdata1 do? Am I safe to remove it? My assumption is that it's a dump of some kind, but that's just a wild guess.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The file `ibdata1` is the system tablespace for the InnoDB infrastructure.

It contains several classes for information vital for InnoDB

- Table Data Pages
- Table Index Pages
- Data Dictionary
- MVCC Control Data
- Undo Space
- Rollback Segments
- Double Write Buffer (Pages Written in the Background to avoid OS caching)
- Insert Buffer (Changes to Secondary Indexes)

Please note ibdata1's place in the InnoDB Universe (on Right Side)

[image: InnoDB Architecture]

You can separate Data and Index Pages from `ibdata1` by enabling [`innodb_file_per_table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table). This will cause any newly created InnoDB table to store data and index pages in an external `.ibd` file.

Example

- [datadir](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir) is `/var/lib/mysql`
- `CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable (...) ENGINE=InnoDB;`, creates `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.frm`

  - `innodb_file_per_table` enabled, Data/Index Pages Stored in `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.ibd`
  - `innodb_file_per_table` disabled, Data/Index Pages Stored in `ibdata1`

No matter where the InnoDB table is stored, InnoDB's functionality requires looking for table metadata and storing and retrieving [**MVCC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) info to support [**ACID compliance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) and [**Transaction Isolation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_isolation).

Here are my past articles on separating table data and indexes from ibdata1

- `Oct 29, 2010` : [**My Original Post in StackOverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261)
- `Nov 26, 2011` :  [ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 6308 in file & The table user_analysis is full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/error-1114-hy000-at-line-6308-in-file-the-table-user-analysis-is-full/8412#8412)
- `Feb 03, 2012` : [Scheduled optimization of tables in MySQL InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12201/scheduled-optimization-of-tables-in-mysql-innodb/12205#12205)
- `Mar 25, 2012` : [Why does InnoDB store all databases in one file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15531/why-does-innodb-store-all-databases-in-one-file/15542#15542)
- `Apr 01, 2012` : [Is innodb_file_per_table advisable?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15906/is-innodb-file-per-table-advisable/15907#15907)

## WHAT TO DO NEXT

You can continue having `ibdata1` stored everything, but that makes doing LVM snapshots real drudgery (my personal opinion).

You need to use my [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261) and shrink that file permanently.

Please run this query:

```
SELECT 
    ((POWER(1024,3)*94 - InnoDBDiskDataAndIndexes))/POWER(1024,3) SpaceToReclaim
FROM
(SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) InnoDBDiskDataAndIndexes
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB') A;
```

This will tell how much wasted space can be reclaimed after applying the InnoDB Cleanup.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My disk quota has since filled completely - before I act on any of the advice in your posts, will I need free space? I note that your original post on SO mentions about doing an SQL dump, but this would presumably create a ~90GB file with nowhere to go.

Comment: mysqldump will only the logical representation of the data pages, not the indexes. You will need another disk mount, perhaps a remote server, to dump the data.

Comment: It returns 91.25350952148438 for me as `SpaceToReclaim`. Is this in megabytes? percent? bytes?

Comment: I know this is too old. But for anyone coming here with the issue, you need to replace the number `94` with whatever is the size of your `ibdata1` file in GB and the `SpaceToReclaim` will give you the size in GB.

Answer (score 9):

That file is `ibdata1`, not `ibdatal` and it contains all of your InnoDB databases. If you delete it, you lose all your data.

For some ideas on how to deal with it, see [How to shrink/purge ibdata1 file in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3456159/1068283).

Answer (score 3):

If you use innodb as MySQL engine by default will store *all* your databases into ibdata1. Also there are log files ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1. Do not delete those files.

Comment: What is delete that file on my server?

Answer (score 0):

What nobody seems to mention is the impact `innodb_undo_log_truncate` setting can have.

Take a look at my answer at [How to shrink/purge ibdata1 file in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456159/how-to-shrink-purge-ibdata1-file-in-mysql/72122560#72122560) in StackOverflow.